# Playframe work 2.2. saving model with reference model ID only

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, data-modeling

I have a question regarding saving a data model in the Play! framework 2.0.  I am building a site similiar to the Zentask example, and one of my data model looks like this more or less:

```java
@Entity
public class Task extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String title;
    public boolean done = false;
    public Date dueDate;
    @ManyToOne
    public User assignedTo;
    public String folder;
    @ManyToOne
    public Project project;

    public static Model.Finder<Long,Task> find = new Model.Finder(Long.class, Task.class);

    public static Task create(Task task, Long project, String folder) {
        task.project = Project.find.ref(project);
        task.folder = folder;
        task.save();
        return task;
    }
}
```

In the above sample code, whenever Task is created, it looks at the project ID and do a db search.  But in reality, it shouldn't be needed as i have a column in the Task table call "project_id" that spring created for me automatically.

Is there a way i can save this Task using this project id directly, without first fetching a Project object using project ID first?

thanks!!